# Parsing XSD using Xerces

Tags: parsing, xsd

I need to parse a generic XSD and create sample XMLs conforming to the XSD. I am using Xerces for Java.

Does Xerces provide support for parsing XSD or do i have to parse it as a regular XML ? If theres support in Xerces, how do i do it? 
Also could someone point to way/technique by which i can create all possible XMLs conforming to an XSD.

if possible please share code link or code snippet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which programming language you want to use but assuming Java, you can use [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) or [JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/xs/) to parse XSD's. You can extract the schema information and then generate the xml's based on the parsed meta data. Or check if [XIG: Xml Instance Generator](http://xml-xig.sourceforge.net/) meets your requirement.